# How can I publish mqtt messages on iot core using AWS credential(sigv4) using python?

Tags: python, amazon-cognito, paho, aws-iot-core

I'm interested if it's possible to use python paho library to publish mqtt messages on AWS iot core and how it's done. Until now I just managed to send mqtt messages using certificates.
The credentials are sigv4(access key id, secret key, session token ) obtained through a Congnito Identity pool.

I just found information on connecting to iot core using certificates and I have already some scripts which use certificates. What I'm interested is how do I handle these credentials in paho.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the problem? Look at this, you connec to AWS IoT Core using certificate that can be generated by AWS IoT.
https://gist.github.com/skirdey/9cdead881799a47742ff3cd296d06cc1

Comment: I need to use aws temporary credentials generated by a cognito identity pool. I don't need to connect a device with x509 certificates. I know how to handle the connection of a thing to iot core. What I want  is to connect users to iot core broker.

Comment: right, so you might want to use custom authorizer in AWS IoT Core then. MQTT client needs to use x509 certificates, by default. By using custom authorizer, you can have a dedicated handler being called (it is a lambda) when a client connects and validate that connection. Have a look here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/custom-authorizer.html